# Converting App Java To Kotlin will Cause Crash on update?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to convert my existing app which is in Java to Kotlin, will it cause crashes to users while updating the app

Comment: Please provide more context. Where you suspect it will fail / possible test results that are not working.

Answer (score 2):

An Android app crashes whenever there’s an unexpected exit caused by an unhandled exception or signal. An app that is written using Java or Kotlin crashes if it throws an unhandled exception, represented by the Throwable class. An app that is written using native-code languages crashes if there’s an unhandled signal, such as SIGSEGV, during its execution.
To answer your question there are chances of crashes in while converting but if done properly by following the steps the chances may become minimal

Please take a look at this link for reference
Link: - https://nilsmagnus.github.io/post/android-annotations-kotlin/